# Voldaren Pariah is exiled while transforming

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What happens if [Voldaren Pariah](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVoldaren%20Pariah%5d) is exiled while transforming? Does it still force target player to sacrifice 3 creatures? Also if it is returned from exile, does it returned already transformed and if it does, does its triggered ability go on the stack then?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "while transforming"? The answer is assuming you mean "after activating the activated ability, but before that ability resolves". Once it has actually "started to transform", it will transform no matter what; it can't be exiled "while transforming".

Answer (score 5):

There are two possible outcomes, depending on when the Volarden Pariah is exiled. These are the only two possibilities; you can't do anything *while* the Pariah is transforming.

### While the activated ability is on the stack

In this case, the Pariah will never transform, and the triggered ability that would make the opponent sacrifice creatures never goes on the stack.

The relevant rules are these:

> - [**112.7.**](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Ability) The source of an ability is the object that generated it. **The source of an activated ability on the stack is the object whose ability was activated.** The source of a triggered ability (other than a delayed triggered ability) on the stack, or one that has triggered and is waiting to be put on the stack, is the object whose ability triggered. To determine the source of a delayed triggered ability, see rules 603.7d–f.
> - [**201.4.**](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Name) Text that refers to the object it’s on by name means just that particular object and not any other objects with that name, regardless of any name changes caused by game effects.
> - [**400.7.**](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Zone) An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence.

If we put these all together, we see that the instruction "Transform Volarden Pariah" really means "Transform the object whose ability was activated". And when the Pariah is exiled, it becomes a new object, so the original object doesn't exist, and the "Transform" instruction just does nothing. Since it never transforms, the triggered ability on the back face never triggers, and the opponent doesn't have to sacrifice three creatures.

## After the activated ability resolves

Once the activated ability resolves, the triggered ability on the back face *immediately* goes on the stack, because [rule 116.2a](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Timing_and_priority) says

> Triggered abilities can trigger at any time, including while a spell is being cast, an ability is being activated, or a spell or ability is resolving. (See rule 603, “Handling Triggered Abilities.”) However, nothing actually happens at the time an ability triggers. **Each time a player would receive priority, each ability that has triggered but hasn’t yet been put on the stack is put on the stack.** See rule 116.5.

And [rule 112.7a](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Ability) says

> Once activated or triggered, an ability exists on the stack independently of its source...

So, even if the Pariah is exiled while the triggered ability is on the stack, the ability still f the resolves, and forces the opponent to sacrifice three creatures.

## If the Pariah re-enters the battlefield

In either case, the Pariah will enter the battlefield face-up. [Rule 711.8](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Double-faced_card) says

> **A double-faced card enters the battlefield with its front face up by default.** If a spell or ability puts it onto the battlefield “transformed,” it enters the battlefield with its back face up.

And rule 400.7 (quoted above) says that it doesn't remember its previous existence, so there's nothing that would change what it does from the default.

Answer (score 2):

target player does not have to sacrifice 3 creatures as this is what happens
1. you sacrifice 3 creatures to transform it
2. Activated ability goes on the stack
3. pariah is exiled
4. Ability resolves
5. the ability states:

> when this **creature** transforms into Abolisher of Bloodlines

From the comprehensive rules

> 406.2. To exile an object is to put it into the exile zone from whatever zone it’s currently in. An exiled card is a **card** that’s been put into the exile zone.

At this point it is no longer a creature but a card in exile meaning that target player won't have to sacrifice anything

When it returns to the battlefield it will be a voldaren pariah and nothing will happen because when a card is moved to an other zone it becomes a new object meaning it will not remember anything that happend before, meaning that it will not remember that you transformed it so it will not be transformed

This is stated in the comprehensive rules here

> 400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence.

Comment: In steps two and four do you mean the activated ability instead of trigger? If you wait until the trigger goes on the stack it is too late.

Comment: I Have changed it

Comment: Isn't the ability that's resolving in step 4 "Transform Voldaren Pariah"? This ability fizzles because it's not on the battlefield anymore, so it never actually transforms. The trigger of "when this creature transforms..." is never actually triggered.

Comment: @Matt It doesn't 'fizzle' (countered due to lack of legal targets), it just does nothing (because the transforming the Pariah is an illegal action it is ignored, but the game still tries to do it)

Comment: This answer is about half right. As Matt mentioned, it's the activated ability that resolves on step 4, and it fails because the object you would have transformed doesn't exist, not because it's "no longer a creature" (so, 112.7 and 400.7 are more relevant than 406.2). And while it's true that it re-enters front face-up, it also never was transformed, so saying it "doesn't remember" is misleading.